# Make a rectangle track using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my raw data, first column is length and second is label:

```
length   label
6.2 sc1__1__62000
0.5 sc1__63001__68000
2.6 sc1__75001__101000
0.7 sc1__103001__110000
....
```

There are 200 entries as such in the file.

I want to make an image as follow, width of each rectangle is same as corresponding length in the table:

[image]

How should I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dplyr to create extra columns for plotting

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
set.seed(20191234)
testdata <- tibble(
    length = sample(1:10,10,replace = TRUE),
    label = replicate(10,paste0(sample(letters,sample(5:15,10,replace = TRUE)),collapse = ""))
) %>%
# plot data
    mutate(
        xmax = cumsum(length),
        xmin = dplyr::lag(xmax,default = 0),
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 2,
        text_x = (xmin+xmax)/2,
        text_y = nchar(label)
    )
```

Create plot using `geom_rect()` and `geom_text()`

```r
text_y_adjust <- -0.032

testdata %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin,xmax = xmax,ymin =ymin,ymax = ymax),
              alpha = 0,color = "black",size = 1) +
    geom_text(aes(x = text_x,y = text_y_adjust * text_y, label = label),angle = 90) +
    ylim(c(-2,2)) +
    theme_void()
```

Note: If you modify any of height of rectangles, `text_y_adjust` ratio, or `ylim`, you need to also change other values correspondingly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it can be done more elegant, but here is a suggestion:

```
#create sample dataframe
length<-c(6.2,0.5,2.6,0.7)
label<-letters[1:4]
d<-data.frame(length,label)

#calculate distance for labels
labelLength<-length[1]/2
for (i in 2:length(length)) {
  labelLength[i]<-sum(length[1:(i-1)])+length[i]/2
}

#create plot
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot()+geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=1,y=length),
                 stat="identity",fill="white",color="red")+coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=labelLength,labels=label)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5,size=20),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"))
plot(p)
```